# Check if item exits in Solidity Mapping structure

Tags: solidity

How i can check if particular item exists in the Mapping list?

```
struct user {
    address userAddress;
    uint[] entries;
}

mapping (address => user) public userInfo;
```

I found such solution here but this solution is not working:

```
require(userInfo[msg.sender].length == 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know if a user exists try the following:

```
require(userInfo[msg.sender].userAddress != address(0));
```

Comment: This answer is the most efficient if your are checking for the existence of  an `address` property.  In the case of `uint` or most other types, you will most likely need to add a flag to your `struct` as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a flag in a `struct`

`struct user{
address userAddress; 
uint[] entries; 
bool isExist;
}
mapping (address => user) public userInfo;
require(userInfo[address].isExist)`

Assign `isExist` to `true` while inserting a record.